# How to remove question mark from my url in Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

Our platform is based on CodeIgniter platform

I was able to remove index.php in my URL link by using `.htaccess rule` But the below type of question mark started appearing on the many of my URL links.

Example url link:

```
www.example.com/**?**/category/subcategory/product/
```

It only shows up in google webmaster results or other SEO crawl tools. As such, it doesn't show when a customer clicks through a website.

Comment: are you sure you don't have that question mark in `$config['base_url']` inside `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: can you write output of your `base_url()` and `site_url()`

Comment: it could be some thing where that link is created in controller? or your htaccess in the main directory

Comment: 1)No we don't have that question mark in $config['base_url'] inside application/config/config.php
2)base_url() Output is https://www.example.com/
  site_url() output is https://www.exmaple.com/

Comment: 3) Our Urls are created in Common Helper. And there is nothing which has question mark in it.

Comment: 4)i have attached my web htaccess below..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /category/m/subcategory/ https://www.example.com/category/subcategory

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AllowOverride` in **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<Directory "C:\Site\Root\Path">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow  
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```